# Saving a transparent image in Android using ALPHA_8

Tags: android, bitmap, compression, alpha

I am creating an overlay image that will sit on top of another image as kind of a filter, accenting the parts of the image I want the user to focus on. Essentially the image will just be solid white in some places and transparent in others with blurring between these segments.

I'm trying to save this image in my database and I can't get the compression to work.  Below is a snippet of code that I'm having issues with.

```
Bitmap image = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Config.ALPHA_8)
... // create image
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream); // always returns false
```

I've tried saving these images to files as well with the same results.  Alternating the compression format, the quality (in the case of JPEGS) did not make a difference either. The only alpha enabled format I could use was ARGB_8888. This is an issue for me as my images are upwards of 1000px x 1000px so I NEED to save on space.  Allocating 4 bytes per pixel is causing memory issues.

Is compressing ALPHA_8 images a known issue on Android? Is there a specific set of bitmap options that need to be set for this to work?  I've looked around the interwebs and SO and while some people seem to have experienced this as well, most seem to simply move to the ARGB_8888 option and don't have a solution for ALPHA_8

Any help is appreciated

Comment: I think this is exactly the same issue as you have: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063764/bitmap-compress-returns-false-for-drawn-image

Comment: Any solutions this? I'm having an issue compressing an image that's semi-transparent in some areas: The areas that are not transparent change colors after compression. If those transparent areas are opaque then the colors don't change.