# Bitmap.compress() is not working on Android Oreo

Tags: android, bitmap, android-8.0-oreo

I have a small bit of code in my app that has been there for more than 2 years, working just fine. We just discovered that it is *not* working on `Oreo` devices. Here's the code:

```
    Bitmap bm = getAsBitmap(200, 100, 5);
    if (bm != null) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, stream);
        return new String(Base64.encode(stream.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT));
    }
```

In all versions of Android prior to `Oreo`(or at least API Level 14-25) this code produces a base64-encoded string serialization of the bitmap. In **`Oreo`** it produces an empty string.

Stepping through it with the debugger, it is clear that the problem is with `bm.compress()` – after running this the stream is still empty. If I debug this same code on my `Nougat` device I can see the stream contains PNG data.

Our build runs `compileSdk 25`, but just to be sure I updated our build to `compileSdk 26` and updated the build tools and support libraries to 26 as well; there was no change in behavior.

Comment: What does `compress` return in these cases? Is there anything at all that looks remotely relevant in the logs?

Comment: This actually turned out not to be the problem I thought it was. Elsewhere in the code someone had changed the bitmap to use `ALPHA_8` configuration, which is apparently broken. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063764/bitmap-compress-returns-false-for-drawn-image